# Discrete Math question, Logical connectives Associative law example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

My book says that $\lnot(P ∨ ((\lnot P) ∧ Q)) ≡ ((\lnot P) ∧ P) ∨ ((\lnot P) ∨ (\lnot Q))$

However, when I follow the Distributive law for $(\lnot P) ∧ (P ∨ (\lnot Q))$ I get

$((\lnot P) ∧ P) ∨ ((\lnot P) ∧ (\lnot Q)) ≢ ((\lnot P) ∧ P) ∨ ((\lnot P) ∨ (\lnot Q))$

Is the book wrong? Or am I missing something?

The book is called Discrete Mathematics by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang 2011

Question is #21 in Supplementary Exercises for Chapter 1

Answer (score 1):

NO; the [book](https://books.google.it/books?id=6cMSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA51) has:

> $\lnot [P \lor (\lnot P \land Q)] \equiv (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$.

First apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic):

> $\lnot[P \lor (\lnot P \land Q)] \equiv \lnot[(P \lor \lnot P) \land (P \lor Q)]$.

Then [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Substitution_form).